Explain non-duplicate
This recent question asks According to LDS, why doesn't omniscient God know about the existence of any other Gods? using Isaiah 44 as a reference.

This question asks about interpretation of Isaiah 43, which has an answer referencing Isaiah 44 as there is common phrasing and the Isaiah 44 verses are reference exactly explaining the wording. It has 2 answers
This question asks How does the LDS Church handle verses that imply there is no one like God? using Isaiah 44 in the question. It has 4 answers
This question asks In the light of this belief that God is an exalted human, how does the LDS Church interpret Hebrews 6:13 and Isaiah 43:10? which contains similar phrasing to Isaiah 44, but the answer easily addresses the point in Isaiah 44. Has single answer
This answer references surrounding Isaiah chapters with similar phrasing as seen in Isaiah 44. Is one of 7 answers
This question asks Mormons believe in more than one god so how do they reconcile this belief with 1 Timothy 1:17? while not mentioning Isaiah does have a very similar theme/question. Has single answer
So far from my reading the top answers all have similar answer, No other Gods concern us (scope) or the text interpretation isn't what is implied.

This meta implies that I (LDS users) might think this is a gotcha question or irrelevant, which is not the case (I do believe the OP thinks its a gotcha or maybe a convince me question). I've tried to address basically any LDS question I come across as I have knowledge/interest on this topic. I would hope my record shows that I'm not afraid/scared of 'hard' or 'obscure' LDS topics.

I'm trying to understand how the question isn't a duplicate and not seeing how this isn't a duplicate. Can someone(mods? OP?) explain how this isn't with specific details/Why the other questions which have multiple positive answers don't answer the question? Do any of the provided answers differ from answers in the other questions? What isn't addressed? This isn't about Truth, this is how does the LDS interpret truth. This isn't convince user X that some denomination doctrine is right, it is how does a denomination address such topics (it doesn't have to align/agree with users viewpoint).

So, I take it that your own answer to all of the above would be 1. No other gods concern us. 2.  The text does not mean what people are saying it means.

@NigelJ yes, specifically #2 in this case, but #1 does apply with OP's implications

The question is still in the close review queue. Who said it wasn't a duplicate? It hasn't been decided as such, so this meta discussion seems premature.

@curiousdannii maybe, except there are only 2 votes after 4 days, mods have looked (at least 2) without responding, comments made by other people make it seem like it is unlikely. OP states he doesn't think it is a dup and the comments are getting long, here is a place where we can look at each of the other questions to cover why it isn't

either I'm right and it's a dup-so close it, or I'm wrong and it's not, but nobody has explained why it isn't.

@depperm It has been fully explained to you why it is not a duplicate . . . . .  but you have not accepted that explanation.

@NigelJ no it hasn't, I've been told why the OP doesn't want to accept the previous answers.  The clarification: this question is not about God's declarations of singularity and how LDS interprets them. the first I'm not sure what they are talking about, the second is kind of ridiculous, don't want to accept how LDS interprets other questions, then asks LDS how they interpret the same verse? Please clarify this

@curiousdannii there was pretty good reason to expect that this question would not get 5 non-mod votes to close, no matter how off-topic it may or may not be. But in any event, the close votes have now expired. In the comments below this Meta I'm trying to give this question a good faith opportunity to distinguish itself as unique & on-topic (including multiple proposed edits for clarity & solid sources), but I'm not yet seeing that such a case can be made.

I propose a very simple definition for a duplicate: if the answer to question B would be the same as the answer to question A and would get there via the same reasoning, question B is a duplicate of question A.
An easy litmus test -- can I answer question B by copy-pasting in an answer that was posted to question A?
In some cases, it may be worth leaving a closed copy of question B on the site to direct traffic to question A. If A & B ask the same question in a different way, having both copies may help more people find the answers, which should be posted on question A.

that is kind of my point though, I could've very easily copied several answers that would answer the question, but OP wasn't convinced of them. I tried a different explanation, but that means its a convince me question. Your answer has scope and biblical text breakdown/comparison section. Good answer, but all of these are stated one way or the other already. If this isn't arguing this isn't a duplicate maybe meta question to amend the duplicate-help page If you are arguing it isn't a duplicate, I'd like how the litmus test doesn't apply

I'm not voting to delete but to mark duplicate which should redirect traffic

@depperm yes my take on the original question was that it could indeed be answered by copy-pasting prior answers to prior questions.
